# Gnome Nautilus thumbnail generation is extremely slow

Tags: gnome, nautilus, thumbnails, 19.04

After updating from 18.10 to 19.04, **thumbnail generation has been extremely slow.** And by that I mean it takes from 10 min to 1 hour for Nautilus to generate ONE thumbnail image.

I already tried clearing `.cache/thumbnails`, but now I'm stuck with no thumbnails and VERY slow thumbnail creation.

What could be causing this? How can I debug this?

Comment: hello, could you provide any logs? also add hardware description, does this problem exist on a fresh install of ubuntu 19.04 instead of an upgrade to 19.04? upgrades have been known to cause a wide array of issues.

Comment: I have tried to learn where Nautilus logs are but I found no pointers on the Internet, just people asking the same thing. If you have any ideas about where to look for the logs, I'd be happy to provide them. Maybe a fresh install would solve this, but I'd like to try to solve this one since this is the last update regression I have up to this time.